# How to prove, that AGL(2, 2) is isomorphic to $S_4$

Tags: group-theory

I know the fact, that every group of order 24, that has more than one Sylow 2- and 3-subgroups is isomorphic to $S_4$, but is there much easier way to prove the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I assume this is the affine general linear group $AGL_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$ consisting of maps $\mathbb{F}_2^2 \to \mathbb{F}_2^2$ of the form $x \mapsto Ax + b$. By definition, this group acts faithfully on a set of $4$ elements, namely $\mathbb{F}_2^2$; this gives a map $AGL_2(\mathbb{F}_2) \to S_4$ which must be injective. (In slightly more detail: given the action of an affine linear transformation $x \mapsto Ax + b$, substituting $x = 0$ produces $b$, then subtracting $b$ produces $x \mapsto Ax$ which is determined by its values on a basis.)

Since $AGL_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$ has $24$ elements ($6$ possibilities for $A$ and $4$ for $b$), the same as $S_4$, the map $AGL_2(\mathbb{F}_2) \to S_4$ must be surjective too, hence an isomorphism.